# Predict a disk's near failure or burnout

Tags: hard-drive, python, hardware-failure, operating-systems

I have a project to submit on computer resource's monitoring, and for that I wish to create a CLI program -for Linux and Windows- that analyses the data provided by SMART each time the computer launches, then predict whether the disk will have a near failure or burnout, I believe there are certain patterns that may indicate that this disk is in a bad status and you better replace it, then send an alert to the user. I think I will go with Python for this project. My question is: How do I interpret this data to know the disk's status? Or what are the patterns that I should look for?

Comment: You could write a book about the subject, it's not a question that can be easily answered on SU.

Comment: To my knowledge SMART does this already, reading the available data and based on certain tresholds, issue a warning. The problem is that sometimes the failures are not detectable by SMART and the drive just stops working without any form of warning. SMART warnings will appear in the bios upon booting and will be written to the eventlog. You can monitor the eventlog but backups are a far better solution to your x-y problem.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Hello sir, if you know a book about this topic then please guide me to it.

Comment: @LPChip We can agree that making a backup up is a must, but that's not always a valid option, in addition to that: the burnout might come when you've forgotten to back-up or had backedup a long time ago or such a scenario, being alerted a short time before the failure might be a great solution.
And although SMART might already does this, my goal is to learn more than solving the problem, and solving the problem is also a great goal of my project... unfortunately my question is closed, and I don't know where's my error and how to solve it...

Comment: The problem is that you're looking for learning recommendations. Any form of recommendation is considered off-topic because it gets out-dated quickly. Instead, google for it, find the information, and if you have questions about the information you already found, narrow it down and ask about that instead. SuperUser is a facts site with answers that can be applied to multiple questions that are similar without any form of speculation or opinion.

Comment: @GuteShel - I said you *could* write a boot about it, not that I know of a book. Besides, there's already tools that do what you want, HD Sentinel is an example.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen correct, there are tools that already do it, but my essential goal is to learn, THEN to solve this issue

Comment: @LPChip Aha now i see why it's closed, thank you, I will try to find answers on google then, or are there any other forums that might provide some guidance, because I tried googling before and I found no results, or maybe my search was poor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not straight-forward to [determine overall disk health](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-smart-what-does-it-do/) from S.M.A.R.T. data. Some items indicate imminent failure, others, such as number of power cycles, give only the vaguest idea, or none. Disk temperature can be high because the device is mounted by the GPU, for example.

There are applications from various disk drive manufacturers and from independent developers, such as [this GNU-licensed project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/), [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/smart-hard-drive-monitor.html), [Acronis Drive Monitor](https://kb.acronis.com/content/58078) and [other alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/acronis-drive-monitor/) that monitor and *evaluate* S.M.A.R.T. statistics and send alerts. It might be an interesting exercise to develop your own application, but at least look at these successful models.

Comment: At least smartmontools do not evaluate SMART data. Smartmontools shows the figures but does not give a recommendation about replacing a disk or predicting a failure with a given probability in a certain time span. This is what I understand when talking about "evaluating". Do the other products do more? I remember Crystal Disk Info evaluating by showing traffic light colours. :)